# Probability and previous events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I realize that probability has no memory of previous outcomes. That is: if a coin is tossed 99 times and comes up heads each of those 99 times, the odds that the next coin toss will result in heads is still 50/50, or if the odds of winning your state's lottery are 1:50,000,000, the odds of the same numbers being drawn in the next draw are still 1:50,000,000. In order for probability to have memory, it would have to somehow keep track of previous outcomes, and this is impossible.
 That being said, what is the difference between those examples and the statements: what are the odds of a coin coming up heads 100 consecutive times, or what are the odds of the same lottery numbers being drawn twice in a row?
I'm thinking that the last statement is simply invalid. It's like asking, what are the odds that a hammer released in normal gravity will fall upward.

Comment: There are plenty of processes with memory!  For example, the event that the temperature gets above 70 today is not independent of the event that it did so yesterday.  And the lottery could exclude recent winners if it wished to....there's nothing impossible about that.

Comment: There is nothing special about the same value being repeated. Let me ask you this question. If I flip a fair coin 5 times, which outcome is more likely: $HTTHT$ or $HHHHH$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common misconception about the coin problem is that $HHHH$ is less likely to happen than, for example, $HTHT$. That *is* the misconception. The probability of getting a run of $HHHH$ is $\frac{1}{2^4}$. The probability of getting a run for $HTHT$ is $\frac{1}{2^4}$ as well. That exact run of $HTHT$ is just as likely to happen as any other.

The difference is that when we managed to record around $2^8$ runs, we would expect to get around $2^4$ observations of each of the following chains:

```
HHHH
HHHT
HHTH
HHTT
HTHH
HTHT
HTTH
HTTT
THHH
THHT
THTH
THTT
TTHH
TTHT
TTTH
TTTT
```

What we expect, however, is that if you count all the $H$ and $T$, you get $2^3$ of the $H$ and $2^3$ of $T$. So there's the $50/50$ again. But you can see that *inside* each chain it is more usual to have a cumulative of $H$ and $T$ nearing one-to-one. **There are more chains with $H$ and $T$ mixed than "pure" chains.**

There's the misconception again. All the chains are equally rare, yet some chains, observed as a whole, have the same proportion of $H$ and $T$. As humans we automatically lump together $HTHT$ with $THTH$, but they in fact the exact opposite. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. I had forgotten that any x number of predefined set of outcomes is the same.